# (React Native) How to implement a ListView/FlatList on a MapView( or other view) like this GIF

Tags: listview, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I want to implement the same UI function as this (Yelp App) on the React Native, and I am using Expo. There is a listview or flatlist on a mapview. The listview has a lower initial position on the top of the mapview. I can scroll the listview up and down while I still can interact with the mapview (click or drag).
[image: The Screen shot from Yelp App]

What I have tried:  I implement a flatlist, and I set its position to absolute, top to a fixed number. this number will be change according to onTouchStart and onTouchMove. I also set scrollEnabled to false. Because if I don't set it to false. The list will still scroll while the whole flatlist view is moving up or down. This approach has a really bad user experience, like the list won't continue scrolling after finger leave the screen. I decided to find a better one.

Please tell me if you have any idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for a library that handles parallax scroll, like [react-native-parallax-scrollview](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-parallax-scroll-view).

You can modify their basic usage example to fit your needs:

```
import ParallaxScrollView from 'react-native-parallax-scroll-view';

// Inside of a component's render() method:
render() {
  return (
    <ParallaxScrollView
      backgroundColor="blue"
      contentBackgroundColor="pink"
      parallaxHeaderHeight={300}
      renderForeground={() => (
       <View style={{ height: 300, flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          // add map component here
        </View>
      )}>
      <View style={{ height: 500 }}>
        // add the list items you want to scroll through here
      </View>
    </ParallaxScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Pat. Thank you for answering the question! I really appreciate that. The solution you provided is really a good one. I have tried and studied it. It seems a little different from what I expect. The mapview should be static lying on the background. It wouldn't move up or down by moving the listview. But I really like your answer!

Comment: Hey Kevin, did you find any solution for your issue? i'm facing something similar